# GLFW Everything is using GL_LINEAR

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I was originally using glut, and I just now switched to GLFW. My GL_NEAREST textures are now using GL_LINEAR, which doesn't work out very well at all(my textures are very low res for style).

```
if (!glfwInit()) return -1;
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "GLFW Test", NULL, NULL);
if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, 1);
glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyboardCallback);
glfwSetCharCallback(window, textCallback);
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouseMotionCallback);
glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseCallback);
printf("Loaded.\n");
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    displayCallback();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
glfwTerminate();
```

This ends up with blocky letters and white rectangles(this might be another issue, but I recall experimenting with GL_LINEAR the same effect).

Texture adding code:

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, s ? GL_NEAREST : GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
#ifdef GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, 4.0);
#endif
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Comment: Where does `s` come from? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: s is defined per texture, some textures do use linear. When I always use GL_NEAREST, the effect is unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was loading some textures before creating the glfw context, not creating the textures at all, which is similar to the particular effect of GL_LINEAR in my program.